# Is there a way to create an if statement in .bat so if a folder fails to open to reboot the PC?

Tags: batch-file

If there isn't a way not a problem just thought i'd throw this question out there since I'm not to familiar with .bat.

Comment: define "a file fails to open"

Comment: I have a folder that will open all the time then some days it will just stop working asking for my credentials over and over again. And it will stop doing that one of two ways either i reboot my pc or log off.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please try to write some code before asking. Visit this website to learn more: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Oh and by the way, nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to the folder in question, and if that fails, reboot.

```
pushd "c:\questionable folder" || shutdown -r -t 60
```

(when experimenting, you have one minute to enter `shutdown -a` to abort the shutdown. After you are sure, it does exactly what you want, you may reduce the timeout)